# Exception: Invalid image data:EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error while using the FadeInImage() for selecting a file which is in local cache of my flutter app.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:6634:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:6491:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodecWithSize (dart:ui/painting.dart:2288:60)
#3      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodecWithSize (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:182:15)
#4      FileImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:1598:20)
<asynchronous suspension>

Path: /data/user/0/blog.myapp.app.dev/cache/mediaCache/2109fa3c-0452-4bc4-875b-5a50e07923e0.jpg
```

Here is the piece of code that is causing the issue :

```
if (imageFile != null) {
      finalImage = FadeInImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: imageSize,
        width: imageSize,
        placeholder: const AssetImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE_ASSET),
        image: FileImage(File(imageFile!.path!)),
      );
      
else if (imageUrl != null) {
      finalImage = Image(
          height: imageSize,
          width: imageSize,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: AdvancedNetworkImage(imageUrl!,
              useDiskCache: true,
              fallbackAssetImage: DEFAULT_IMAGE_ASSET,
              retryLimit: 0));
```

The else block uses network image connected to my backend postgres sql based django3.2 api using imageUrl.However, the error trace shows FileImage as a likely culprit.

Help appreciated.

EDIT. Upon adding a try catch block:

When I upload an image :
The profile image box doesn't get updated(it should with the image).
Upon clicking Save button (when image goes to the backend) :

I get :

> Upload a valid image.The file you uploaded with either not an image or a corrupted image.

upon inspecting the backend api : I have

```
my-api            | 2023-11-06 06:56:24,421 django.request WARNING  Bad Request: /api/auth/user/
my-api            | 2023-11-06 06:56:24,422 django.server WARNING  "PATCH /api/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 400 104
```

Comment: the image fetched from your database is not in the correct format. In `finalImage = FadeInImage`, can you add a `try-catch` function and show us what the catch error print says?

Comment: Sure. give me some time to get the result.

Comment: @Texv. Results are updated in the question.

Comment: The issue is in your API code. Can you show us how you handle the image in your API? I'm not too experienced with django so someone with more experience in that field might be able to find the issue with your api

Comment: The issue surfaced after changing the database engine from mysql to postgres sql and updating pubspec.yaml to latest versions. Also, the 1st step of the profile box itself not showing the cached image which should appear(it doesnt), the api part is the 2nd step. I now sense the local caching & eventually the FileImage() (shown in the trace) is the issue. FileImage is what Creates an object that decodes a [File] as an image. I wonder what makes FileImage() work abnormally